# RelativeLayout Right

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to do an app that will have groups of three views. To start with the RelativeLayout, I am just going to use TextViews. However it is not working. In the following code, the second textview appears randomly in the screen, and I detected that is because the `rl1.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, tv.getId());` is not working. I tried `rl1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, bt.getId());` and was able to locate it wherever I wanted.

```
        View bt = findViewById(R.id.button);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setId(0);
        tv.setText("This is a test");
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rl = 
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        rl.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        rl.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, bt.getId());
        rl.setMargins(30, 20, 0, 0);
        tv.setLayoutParams(rl);

        rLayout.addView(tv);

        TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
        tv1.setId(1);
        tv1.setText("still testing this");
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rl1 = 
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        rl1.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, tv.getId());
        rl1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, tv.getId());
        rl1.setMargins(30,20,0,0);
        tv1.setLayoutParams(rl1);

        rLayout.addView(tv1);
```

As a result of this code I have the first textView exactly where I want it, but the second one is aligned at the top with the relative layout, and horizontally starts at the same place as the first one (I am assuming because the both have margins of 30 at the left).

Comment: Why do you build your UI in Java? couldn't you use a normal XML layout for that?

Comment: No, because it is supposed to fetch data from data base and show it. This is just a sample to get used with the RelativeLayout. I do not know how many elements I am going to end up showing

Comment: Well, the correct answer is actually: **YES**... Surprised? Have a look on how to populate a custom ListView from a database.

Comment: Did you thought about using a ListView to display the data from the database?

Comment: Yes, I thought about the ListView, but this app is going to be for tablets only and I wanted to have two "tables" of data next to each other to fill the space in landscape mode. @Frank, I don't understand what the YES answer is for.

Comment: You can also put two ListViews beside each other for the landscape mode. and all with XML code, no need of java.

Comment: I'm going to try that. However, I am really intrigued why this code doesn't work.

Comment: Building a UI in code is never a good idea. It may lead to several hard-to-find errors.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `/res/layout-land` folder for two ListViews when your tablet is in the landscape mode:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" >
    </ListView>


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the portrait mode the xml file could look like this (located in the `/res/layout-port` folder):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:** Of course both files have to have the same name so in the activity you just have to write `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` when your files are named `activity_main.xml`.